# SurfaceTexture preview for camera2 stretches on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I'm developing a camera2 app. Everything is working fine on Nexus 5 and Nexus 4, but on LG G2 preview for video is stretched (only for back camera, for front camera everything is fine). I'm setting SurfaceTexture the next way:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        float ratioSurface = width > height ? (float) width / height : (float) height / width;
        float ratioPreview = (float) mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight;
        int scaledHeight = height;
        int scaledWidth = width;
        if (ratioPreview > ratioSurface) {
            scaledHeight = (int) (((float) mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) * width);
        } else if (ratioPreview < ratioSurface) {
            scaledWidth = (int) (height / ((float) mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight));
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
    }
```

After setAspectRatio() I'm called setSurfaceTexture():

```
private void setSurfaceTexture(Size size) {
        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        int width = resource.cameraTexture.getWidth();
        int height = resource.cameraTexture.getHeight();
        int rotation = controller.getRotation();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), width / 2, height / 2);
        }
        resource.mForegroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                resource.cameraTexture.setTransform(matrix);
            }
        });
    }
```

I was trying to use SurfaceView, but result is the same: when switches to video mode, preview is stretched. I tried many ways, but result is always the same.
Please, help me...

EDIT: Video is still stretched on LG G2 with CyanogenMod, but in phones with official Lollipop the issue was next: LEGACY devices not always support preview video 16:9, so I've changed video size to 4:3.

Comment: I'm not sure why your approach isn't working, but you may want to consider setting the aspect ratio with the TextureView matrix instead of using the View layout. For an example, see `adjustAspectRatio()` here: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java#L211

Comment: @fadden I've tried this approach, but it isn't working too :(

Comment: Are you sure the aspect ratio you're using is the actual aspect ratio of the video? AFAIK the front and back cameras are not guaranteed to support the same sizes.

Comment: @fadden, yes, I've debuged app and I'm sure, that my preview size (aspect ratio) is the same as video size...

Comment: If the size of the View and the size of the camera preview frames match, you will not see stretching. One of them is off. You can try `adb shell dumpsys window` and `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` to see what exactly the system believes is going on. You can find a brief explanation of some of the HWC summary fields here: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#composition

Comment: @fadden, thanks for help, I've tried to hardcode the size of view and default buffer size, but it still stretches... May it be because of LEGACY support of camera2?

Comment: @Graisie Have you found the solution yet? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32853401/192373

Comment: @Graisie, Have u fixed this problem?

Comment: @user1154390, no, preview is still stretched, even in other apps (which use camera2 api) on the phone with cyanogen. I've rewrote the app with first api.